# aggregate functions for boolean field

Tags: influxdb

I want a continuous query on a stream of boolean fields, to downsample them.
So I need an aggregate function to convert a series of booleans to one. In my case I would need AND().
I don't seem to find such a function, in fact, none of the aggregate functions work on boolean types:
`ERR: unsupported sum iterator type: *influxql.booleanInterruptIterator`

Does there exist another way to aggregate boolean values? Custom aggregate functions are not supported as I understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking it's easier to convert my booleans to 0 and 1..also for graphing in Grafana it will be easier to work with.